# Batch file: Run command and loop at same time

Tags: windows, command-line, batch, script

I want to run a simple batch script that basically includes only two Wireshark commands:

```
@echo off
dumpcap -i 1 -f "tcp port 8800" -a "filesize:100" -n -w "data.pcap" 
&&
:loop
  start tshark -r data.pcap -T fields -Y "frame contains ERROR" -e data.data > data.txt
  timeout /t 5
  echo hi
  goto :loop
```

However, only the first command `dumpcap....` will run. I can't get the loop to work. It works when I put the loop in a separate batch file, but that's not what I want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to remove the line that contains `&&`. If you run your script from the Command Prompt (instead of double-clicking it in Windows) you should be getting this error:

> && was unexpected at this time.

The `&&` is a conditional command separator that means "run the following command only if the proceeding command was successful." However it has no meaning on a line of its own.

The working script should look like this:

```
@echo off
dumpcap -i 1 -f "tcp port 8800" -a "filesize:100" -n -w "data.pcap" 
:loop
  start tshark -r data.pcap -T fields -Y "frame contains ERROR" -e data.data > data.txt
  timeout /t 5
  echo hi
  goto :loop
```

You can learn more about this command at [this StackOverflow question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8055371/2227908).

Comment: this doesn't work, unfortunately. when the dumpcap command starts, it opens up a new cmd window and ignores the loop completely. i don't know how to avoid this.

Comment: That information belongs in your question. Put `start` or `start /w` in front of the dumpcap command.